# haskell elegant way to filter (reduce) sequences of duplicates from infinte list of numbers

Tags: haskell, filter, sequence

This is a function that produces an infinite  list of random numbers

```
import System.Random
values :: [Int]
values = map fst $ scanl (\(r, gen) _ -> randomR (1,10) gen) (randomR (1,10) (mkStdGen 1)) $ repeat ()
```

I want to reduce sequences for duplicate elements into one element e.g
[2,3,4,1,7,7,7,3,4,1,1,1,3,..] -> [2,3,4,1,7,3,4,1,3,..]

So, I need some elegant function **"f"** from [Int] -> [Int] that do this.
Also, it must work with an infinite list lazily, so if I run

```
f values
```

it must not hang and output data in real-time

Comment: `f = map head . group`

Comment: Your expression for `values` can be simplified to `randomRs (1,10) (mkStdGen 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with [**`group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) to make a list of groups. So for the given sample data, this will generate:

```
Prelude> import Data.List(group)
Prelude Data.List> group [2,3,4,1,7,7,7,3,4,1,1,1,3]
[[2],[3],[4],[1],[7,7,7],[3],[4],[1,1,1],[3]]
```

Then we can for each sublist only yield the first element with `head`, we know that such element exists, since otherwise it would never have constructed a new group in the first place:

```
Prelude Data.List> map head (group [2,3,4,1,7,7,7,3,4,1,1,1,3])
[2,3,4,1,7,3,4,1,3]
```

This thus means that you can define `f` as:

```
import Data.List(group)

f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f = map head . group
```

This works on infinite lists as well. For example if we end the list with an infinite list of `5`s, then it processes the list until that five and keeps looking for a new value:

```
Prelude Data.List> map head (group (2 : 3 : 4 : 1 : 7 : 7 : 7 : 3 : 4 : 1 : 1 : 1 : 3 : repeat 5))
[2,3,4,1,7,3,4,1,3,5
```

or we can make use of the [**`group :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => f a -> [NonEmpty a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:group) of `Data.List.NonEmpty`:

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty(group)
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NE

f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f = map NE.head . group
```

Comment: the generally safe way to do the same as `map head` is `concatMap (take 1)`.

Comment: @WillNess: but here we know that the sublists will not be empty, there is a variant of `group` that generates `NonEmpty`s...

Comment: well, technically, I did not say "technically". :)