# Haskell sequence of IO actions processing with filtration their results in realtime+perfoming some IO actions in certain moments

Tags: haskell, io, sequence

I want to do some infinite sequence of IO actions processing with filtration their results in realtime+perfoming some IO actions in certain moments:
We have some function for reducing sequences (see my question [haskell elegant way to filter (reduce) sequences of duplicates from infinte list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65437663/haskell-elegant-way-to-filter-reduce-sequences-of-duplicates-from-infinte-list?noredirect=1#comment115691746_65437663)):

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f = map head . group
```

and expression

```
join $ sequence <$> ((\l -> (print <$> l)) <$> (f <$> (sequence $ replicate 6 getLine)))
```

if we run this, user can generate any seq of numbers, for ex:

```
1
2
2
3
3
"1"
"2"
"3"
[(),(),()]
```

This means that at first all getLine actions performed (6 times in the example and at the end of this all IO actions for filtered list performed, but I want to do IO actions exactly in the moments then sequencing reduces done for some subsequences of same numbers.

How can I archive this output:

```
1     
2
"1"
2     
3
"2"        
3
3
"3"
[(),(),()]
```

So I Want this expression not hangs:

```
 join $ sequence <$> ((\l -> (print <$> l)) <$> (f <$> (sequence $ repeat getLine)))
```

How can I archive real-time output as described above without not blocking it on infinite lists?

Comment: Please describe what you want to generate, rather than assuming it is obvious by looking at your existing code.

Comment: Are you assuming that the input is increasing order, and you want output each unique number when the next larger number is input?

Comment: No, it can be a sequence of any numbers, duplicate subsequences of the same numbers must be reduced to one number.

Comment: So what exactly makes you decide to output , for example, `"1"` when you do? What made you wait until after 2 was input, and what would happened if 1 appeared in the output again later? The output doesn't seem to be produced either as early or as late as possible.

Comment: @chepner if the next input differs from the previous, this means that seq is 'broken' and we can perform print action of the previous number.

Comment: Ah, ok, duplicate *subsequences*. I missed that distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution with iterateUntilM

```
iterateUntilM (\_->False) (\pn -> getLine >>= (\n -> if n==pn then return n else (if pn/="" then print pn else return ()) >> return n) ) ""
```

I don't like some verbose with

```
(if pn/="" then print pn else return ())
```

if you know how to reduce this please comment)

ps.
It is noteworthy that I made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqsp2KY-4rE) about this function :)
And could not immediately apply it :(

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a job for a streaming library, like [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImportQualifiedPost #-}
module Main where

import Streaming
import Streaming.Prelude qualified as S

main :: IO ()
main =
      S.mapM_ print
    . S.catMaybes
    . S.mapped S.head
    . S.group
    $ S.replicateM 6 getLine
```

"streaming" has an API reminiscent to that of lists, but works with effectful sequences.

The nice thing about streaming's version of [`group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:group) is that it doesn't force you to keep the whole group in memory if it isn't needed.

---

The least intuitive function in this answer is [`mapped`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:mapped), because it's very general. It's not obvious that streaming's version of [`head`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:head) fits as its parameter. The key idea is that the [`Stream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#t:Stream) type can represent *both* normal effectful sequences, and sequences of elements on which groups have been demarcated. This is controlled by changing a functor type parameter ([`Of`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Of.html#t:Of) in the first case, a nested `Stream (Of a) m` in the case of [grouped `Stream`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#g:5)).

`mapped` let's you transform that functor parameter while having some effect in the underlying monad (here `IO`). `head` processes the inner `Stream (Of a) m` groups, getting us back to an `Of (Maybe a)` functor parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Without a 3rd-party library, you can lazily read the contents of standard input, appending a dummy string to the end of the expected input to force output. (There's probably a better solution that I'm stupidly overlooking.)

```
import System.IO

print_unique :: (String, String) -> IO ()
print_unique (last, current) | last == current = return ()
                             | otherwise = print last

main = do
  contents <- take 6 <$> lines <$> hGetContents stdin
  traverse print_unique (zip <*> tail $ (contents ++ [""]))
```

`zip <*> tail` produces tuples consisting of the `i`th and `i+1`st lines without blocking. `print_unique` then immediately outputs a line if the following line is different.

Essentially, you are sequencing the output actions as the input is executed, rather than sequencing the input actions.